# If I change ecu and ignition with the keys wil engine start or will need coding or change pump.ldv van with transit engine ECU and immobiliser

Tags: electronic-control-module

If I change ECU and ignition with keys will engine start or will need coding or change and fuel pump . it's ldv convoy 2004 with transit engine ECU and immobiliser

Answer (score 0):

I believe for the 04 Transits (mk6?) the immobilizer is in the ECU. So long as the ecu and key are matched then that should satisfy the immobilizer. I believe there is some coding between the ecu and the module on fuel pump tho that may prevent the engine from running if not matched. You may need to move that as well or code the ecu for the one on your LDV. Make sure to research this before just taking my word on it though, I have no first hand experience on these. My reply is just based off memory reading about it in international repair forums.

Comment: Thanks.Locksmiths said the same,it MAYBE need to code the pump to the new ECU, which still leaves me with 50 % chance.i can by ECU and ignition with keys for150£ on eBay.but if I have to mess with the pump it will go in the bushes and will be used as spares.